# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't allow to input numbers

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to type numbers in my `AutoCompleteTextView` but nothing happens. I can write all other symbols except `[0-9]` with the virtual keyboard. Please help me.

```
        <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/group_edittext_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="@string/group"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/apptheme_textfield_activated_holo_light"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

Comment: android:inputType="textCapCharacters" change to  android:inputType="text"

Comment: Yeah, I done it already, but also I want to have inputted letters in uppercase (((

Comment: hey try this android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters"

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code and it's working just fine, but if it's not working in your case then you just remove `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`. I'm sure it wilw accept all characters.